# Menu ActionBarActivity not work after calling supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

Tags: android, menu, android-support-library, android-actionbaractivity

I'm working with the library and compatibility with Drawer menu.

After calling the supportInvalidateOptionsMenu () function; the popup menu fails to appear, leaving only the core flow icon.

Any solution for this?

Do this in my ActMain (main activity for very fragments)

```
  @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        hideMenuItems(menu, !drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void hideMenuItems(Menu menu, boolean visible)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {

            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(visible);
        }
    }
```

> Note: there is only one menu item with a submenu. In this submenu, all
>   items are visible, but when I click on the item that is to appear in
>   the ActionBar the other items, they simply do not appear more than one
>   time. This only occurs in version 2.3 of Android. In the upper works
>   well.

Answer (score 1):

The `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` is only valid for `android 2.3 and lower` that is why it has a prefix `support` on it, more likely if you use that the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is **not called** when you are trying to run it in `android 2.3 and above`.

**solution:**

You can check first if the device is `2.3 and lower` or `above`, if it is **above** you use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` for updating/calling the `onPrepareOptionsMenu`

Comment: Yes, I do it, the problem is that calling invalidate the submenu no longer appears you know? It is only the main menu, if I click to see more options, these options do not appear. Seems to be a bug in the library so googled.

Comment: @CíceroMoura are you sure that `drawerOpen` is true??

Comment: @CíceroMoura make sure that you invalidate it when closing and opening the `mDrawerLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

In onOptionsItemSelected method I check the version of the SDK, if <11 then create a support PopUpMenu using v7, if not, let clicking on options normally.

In the end, looked like this:

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        menu.clear();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10)
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.gingerbread_core_flow, menu);
        else 
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.finances, menu);


        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10)
        {
            android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu popupMenu = new android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu(getActivity(),txtMonth);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.finances_gingerbread_items);
            popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.search).setVisible(false);
            popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.ordernar_por).setVisible(false);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new                 android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem)
                {
                    onItemSelected(menuItem);

                    return false;
                }
            });

            popupMenu.show();
        }
        else
            return onItemSelected(item);

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

In onItemSelected I validate method which option it clicked.

This solves my problem.

The txtMonth view is at the top, so to the user it makes no difference.

I know it's not the best solution, but I need to solve it fast.